# IOS 10 Swift 3 Core plot does not display Y grid

Tags: ios, swift3, core-plot

I am trying to use coreplot pod and I am not able to figure out how to display "Y Axis" grid nor ticks on Axes itself, please have a look at my code bellow and advise

Thank you.`

```
        let yAxis = axisSet.yAxis
    yAxis?.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicy.fixedInterval
    yAxis?.majorIntervalLength = plotYInterval as NSNumber?
    yAxis?.minorTicksPerInterval = 4
    yAxis?.minorTickLength = 5
    yAxis?.majorTickLength = 7
    yAxis?.title = "Degree C"
    yAxis?.titleOffset = 5
    yAxis?.labelFormatter = axisLabelFormatter
```

Hi Eric,

here the full init code

```
func initLinePlot() {
    //Initialize and display Graph (x and y axis lines)
    graph = CPTXYGraph(frame: graphView.bounds)
    self.graphView.hostedGraph = self.graph;

    //apply styling to Graph
    graph?.apply(CPTTheme(named: CPTThemeName.plainWhiteTheme))

    //set graph backgound area transparent
    graph?.fill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.clear())
    graph?.plotAreaFrame?.fill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.clear())
    graph?.plotAreaFrame?.fill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.clear())

    //This removes top and right lines of graph
    graph?.plotAreaFrame?.borderLineStyle = CPTLineStyle(style: nil)
    //This shows x and y axis labels from 0 to 1
    graph?.plotAreaFrame?.masksToBorder = false

    // set padding for graph from Left and Bottom
    graph?.paddingBottom = 30;
    graph?.paddingLeft = 20;
    graph?.paddingRight = 0;
    graph?.paddingTop = 0;

    //Define x and y axis range
    let plotSpace = graph?.defaultPlotSpace
    plotSpace?.allowsUserInteraction = true
    plotSpace?.delegate = self;
```

//       self.resetPlotRange()

```
    let axisSet = graph?.axisSet as! CPTXYAxisSet;

    let axisLabelFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    axisLabelFormatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = false
    axisLabelFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal


    //Define x-axis properties
    //x-axis intermediate interval 2
    let xAxis = axisSet.xAxis
    xAxis?.majorIntervalLength = plotXInterval as NSNumber?
    xAxis?.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
    xAxis?.minorTickLength = 10;
    xAxis?.majorTickLength = 15;
    xAxis?.title = "Time (s)"
    xAxis?.titleOffset = 10;
    xAxis?.labelFormatter = axisLabelFormatter



    //Define y-axis properties
    let yAxis = axisSet.yAxis
    yAxis?.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicy.fixedInterval
    yAxis?.majorIntervalLength = plotYInterval as NSNumber?
    yAxis?.minorTicksPerInterval = 4
    yAxis?.minorTickLength = 5
    yAxis?.majorTickLength = 7
    yAxis?.title = "Degree C"
    yAxis?.titleOffset = 5
    yAxis?.labelFormatter = axisLabelFormatter


    //Define line plot and set line properties
    linePlot = CPTScatterPlot()
    linePlot?.dataSource = self
    graph?.add(linePlot!, to: plotSpace)

    //set line plot style
    let lineStyle = linePlot?.dataLineStyle!.mutableCopy() as! CPTMutableLineStyle
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 2
    lineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.blue()
    linePlot!.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;


    //set graph grid lines
    let gridLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    gridLineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.red()
    gridLineStyle.lineWidth = 2// 0.5               
    xAxis?.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle
    yAxis?.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle
    yAxis?.majorTickLineStyle = gridLineStyle       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `fixedInterval` labeling policy, the `majorIntervalLength` determines the distance between major tick marks. By default, numbering starts at zero (0), so tick marks will only be visible if they fall within the `yRange` of the plot space. For example, if the ticks are 10 units apart, but the range only covers five units, there may not be any visible ticks in that range.

The default line style for major tick marks is a black line one (1) point wide. Set the `majorTickLineStyle` to use a different style. Grid lines are not drawn by default. Set the `majorGridLineStyle` to show the grid lines. There are corresponding properties for minor tick marks and grid lines, too.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you for your replay, I tried to adjust grid line style, but it still doesnt work for some reasons, please see code bellow:          //set graph grid lines
        let gridLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
        gridLineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.red()
        gridLineStyle.lineWidth = 2             
        xAxis?.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle
        yAxis?.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle
        yAxis?.majorTickLineStyle = gridLineStyle

Comment: What is the `yRange` (location and length)? What is the value of `plotYInterval`? Is the axis line visible without tick marks?

Comment: Plot interval = 10 yRange = 60

Comment: Can you see the axis line?

Comment: yep, both axis ie X and Y are present , also running app on real device "IPAD" using IOS10 and latest XCODE

Comment: Can you post the axis setup code? Without specifics, we're just guessing at solutions.

Comment: hi Eric, I have update code in to the question , please have a look and advise

Comment: I dropped your axis code into one of the Core Plot demos and the axes and grid lines appeared fine. Be sure the `plotXInterval` and `plotYInterval` have the expected values during the setup process.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you for your replay. Quick question: majorIntervalLength what this parameter is specifying ie I have set it to 10, and my data is changing from 0 to 50, also I have declared it as Float. Can you please advise? Thank you!

Comment: The `majorIntervalLength` determines the distance between major tick marks. With a plot range of 0 to 50 and interval length 10, you should have six tick marks (at 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, and 50).

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you for your replay. Number what I am trying to plot,(Y)  is float_32 does it make any difference?  Also is there  way to make sure all axis are properly set up, ie to see all grids and tick lines?

Comment: Core Plot will plot `double` or `NSDecimal` values. Anything else will be converted one of those types internally based on the `cachePrecision` setting. Any required conversion happens as values are read from the datasource. The axis line and major and minor ticks default to a 1 point wide black line. Grid lines are off by default. To make the grid lines visible or change the axis and/or tick style, set the corresponding line style.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you for your replay, it looks like I am setting grid line style, grid line color, and width of the grid line. Also major and minor ticks are set for both axis, I do see perfect plot is being plotted... What else can contribute to the fact that I do not see gird lines nor major/minor ticks on the axis?  Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code posted in the question. I would double check that the major intervals are being set to the values you expect using log statements or the debugger.